How to define the set which is indexed in this notation for an indexed set?
hi I'm learning about indexed sets but I can't figure out how this notation works.
$$
\{A_i\}_{i \in N}
$$
It tells me that 'i' is a member of the set of natural numbers, but doesn't tell me what set 'Ai' is a member of. How is the reader meant to know what set is being indexed?

I agree that the notation is incomplete as it stands.  All we know is that we  have a sequence of...somethings.  Could be numbers of some sort, could be sets, could be functions...could be all manner of things. There should be something else telling us that, say, $A_i\in \mathbb R$ or whatever.

usually, this will be explained in the text surrounding the expression.

For example, you can define a family of intervals, where $A_i = [-\frac{1}{i} ; \frac{1}{i}]$.
Thus,
$\cap \{A_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}} = \{0\}$,
$\cup \{A_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}} = [-1 ; 1]$.
